# Custom sitemap.xml for opencart multi stores

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, xml-sitemap

I am new to Opencart. I have 3 stores on one opencart platform and custom sitemap.xml file for each store. Any help would be appreciated in uploading/setting them.

Answer (score 0):

so what problem? every multistore have one database and 3 folder with store files, and home directory have sitemap.

Comment: Hi Mark Vasyl, so do you want me to upload the file to it's theme folder?

Comment: i mean, every multistore have a folder:

Comment: for example. store1 (mydomain.com/folder_your_site/sitemap.xml) store2(store2.mydomain.com/folder_your_site/sitemap.xml) and every folder have a htacces, and inside you write your sitemap xml. google see every site on subdomain its another website, its normal.

Comment: Hi Mark, there is only one .htaccess file at the root level. Store folders don't have any .htaccess files. So, I don't think store folder is not a right place to upload sitemap.xml